# Get exit code of command executed by the linux script command

Tags: scripting

Note this is run on a debian linux environment

I have the following sample script called HelloWorld.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello World"
exit 1
```

I then run the following command

```
script -c ./HelloWorld.sh foo ; echo $?
```

$? returns 0 which is expected since the script command itself ran successfully. However, I want the return code HelloWorld.sh which would be 1 if I just ran the following command.

```
bash HelloWorld.sh ; echo $?
```

Looking at the man page, I see that the script command doesn't return anything so the following wouldn't help either

```
return_code=`script -c ./HelloWorld.sh foo`
```

The question I would like to ask is whether there is a way that I can get the return value of HelloWorld.sh when running it in the context of the script command such as sending the exit value to the parent shell. If not, how would you recommend doing it?

My possible answers on how I would do it if I can't use the script command

1. Have HelloWorld.sh write to shared memory using the shm API
2. Have HelloWorld.sh write to a file

Both methods require cleanup of the shared memory object and the file respectively, so I am asking for my own personal knowledge whether there is a simpler solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual page of script

```
 -e, --return
         Return the exit code of the child process.  Uses the same format
         as bash termination on signal termination exit code is 128+n.
```

So this should work

```
$ script -e -c ./HelloWorld.sh; echo $?
Script started, file is typescript
Hello World
Script done, file is typescript
1
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. It appears that I should have clarified in my question that the man page I was looking at was from a centos 6 system which didn't have that option. I will check the server tomorrow for the option.

Answer (score 3):

man script,

```
   -e, --return
          Return the exit code of the child process.  Uses the same format
          as bash termination on signal termination exit code is 128+n.
```